# Distribute a cell value into a column at specific range

Tags: excel, vba

i want to distribute the cell value down to the column but at specific cell.
@taller last time you give me the code i tried it it working well see in [pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0nsV.png)but there is little problem. The very first is that if value is less then the number of cells it distribute 0 all the column and give all the value to the last cell see in [pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVuqC.png).  but i want to distribute it to the column no matter how much value is distributing atleast it should be 1 and where the distributing finish it place the cursor their.
And second thing is that if i want to distribute the value from any cell it should start from their for example in [pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENr2P.png) if i select cell j10 it should divide the above value 8 down to the last j20 cell.

Comment: when "H6" is distributed to "H7:H10", is it random?

Comment: What is the expected result if  Values division by Customer not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Like This ?

```
=LEFT($L$1/COUNTA(K:K),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(K2:K5),1,1000,0))
```

[image]

Comment: As on the picture there are headers of the table. You count the headers.

Comment: yes, same as the example picture

Comment: @Sunny bro i tried it but it not working it showing  #Name? error

Comment: @hurairabhatti what ur excel version ?

Comment: @sunny its 2016

Comment: @hurairabhatti Does your Excel have this function? (Left, Counta, & Sequence), because I don't know what formulas are available in Excel 2016

Comment: @Sunny sequence function is not avalible

Answer (score 0):

- Dynamically determine the size of data table
- *Note:* If the division of `Value` by `Customer` results is a non-integer quotient, the remainder is added to the `last customer`. Please provide specific details if you have an alternative logic in mind.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowCnt As Long, c As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long, Remainder As Double, iVal As Double
    Const START_COL = 8 ' Col H
    Const START_ROW = 7
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, START_COL - 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= START_COL And LastRow >= START_ROW Then
        RowCnt = LastRow - START_ROW + 1
        For Each c In Range(Cells(START_ROW - 1, START_COL), Cells(START_ROW - 1, LastCol))
            Remainder = c.Value Mod RowCnt
            iVal = (c.Value - Remainder) / RowCnt
            c.Offset(1).Resize(RowCnt - 1).Value = iVal
            c.Offset(RowCnt).Value = iVal + Remainder
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: it workiing but it has some problem  for example if i increase the number of cells it gives 0 to all the cells and on last cell it give all the value see above pic. i want to distribute the value to the last cell if the value is less it should not give 0 but where this value is distributed it should select that cell where the value is finished.  Could you make it that if place courser in that column cell it distribute from that select cell toward down e.g if i select j12 it should distribute value 8 towards down without giving 0 value

Comment: Please edit your post to upload a screenshot. It's helpful to understand your question.